# Disable SASS auctocompile in Adobe Bracket for other files than main.scss

Tags: json, sass, adobe-brackets

I just want to disable autocompile for all other files than my main.scss in Adobe Bracket. I added this in my preference.json but dosen't work for me so far. `

```
{
/* disable compiling other files that aren't the "main" file */
"sass.enabled": false,
"path": {
    "scss/styles.scss": {
        "sass.enabled": true,
        "sass.options": {
            "outputDir": "../css/",
            "includePaths": [],
            "sourceComments": true,
            "outputStyle": "nested"
        }
    }
  }
}`
```

My main file is styles.scss but when I save the preference.json no change happens.

Comment: The preferences file in Brackets by default is `brackets.json`

Comment: Even if I paste these lines at the end of brakets.json, when I create a new file named styles.scss, it is automatically compiled.